# When reporting a Facebook account as hacked or compromised will Facebook pass it on to the authorities

Tags: facebook, hacked, legal

If I report my Facebook account as being hacked or 'compromised' will Facebook pass the matter on to the authorities?

Comment: Which authorities? The internet police?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on which way you were hacked. In most cases Facebook will not do anything, as it is more of a petty crime which probably happens a lot, and can be hard to prove. On the other hand if this was a large scale hacking attack where Facebook servers may have been compromised, then yes Facebook would most likely report the hacker(s) to their respected authorities.

*This is not official legal advice*